# Eclipse - How to change background color of tooltips for hidden text/too long text

Tags: java, colors, eclipse, color-theme

I use Eclipse Mars dark theme and have been trying to get colors right to my best effort.

When you mouseover/hover an item which has a text too long and got partially hidden by window, a tooltip will show up, as shown on the below image.

[image: Eclipse Balloon background color]

As you can see, either the tooltip foreground color needs to change to black or background to dark color.

It does not look like the Window system ToolTip and I could not find the corresponding Eclipse setting covers that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi Rich, I am glad I am not the only one aware of the issue but unfortunately I do not think I found the solution at the end.  I just upgraded my iOS from 8 to 9 and recognizes that Apple has changed the font from Helvetica to San Francisco and I do not like it.   Sometimes we need to accept world is not perfect.  I do not remember if I raised the issue to any Eclipse forum.  I would hope I could retire earlier and have time to look into Eclipse source to find out the reason.

Comment: I have filed a bugzilla, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490409